# Is it possible to restore a datomic backup to a local dynamodb

Tags: datomic

I'm trying to diagnose some performance issues, so I have a the Datomic transactor running locally backed by a local instance of DynamoDB. What I can't figure out is how to populate it from a backup of our primary Datomic environment. I know the basic command is:

```
>datomic restore-db s3://<BUCKET> datomic:ddb://<REGION>/<DB-NAME>
```

but how to I tell datomic to use the local dynamodb? It seems to only accept the valid AWS regions for REGION. I've also tried using `datomic:ddb-local` as the protocol but no luck there either.

How do I form the target URI? Or is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use a ddb-local URI as indicated here: http://docs.datomic.com/storage.html#dynamodb-local

It will be something like: `datomic:ddb-local://localhost:8000/my-table/my-db-name?aws_access_key_id=ABC&aws_secret_key=DEF`, assuming you're running ddb-local at localhost on port 8000.

Note that the ddb-local protocol does require an access key and secret, even though they are ignored.

Best,

Marshall